# Regular expressions in PHP / find "<a> </a>"

Tags: php, html, regex, hyperlink

I want to check a textarea. If the user enter some links in the textarea, php should automatically tag the links. I'm using this code:

```
    $message = "text with some link within"; 

    $url = '@(?!<a[^>]*?>)(http)?(s)?(://)?(([a-zA-Z])([-\w]+\.)+([^\s\.]+[^\s]*)+[^,.\s])(?![^<]*?</a>)@';


    if(preg_match($url, $message) == 1){

    $message = preg_replace($url, '<a href="http$2://$4" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="$0">$0</a>', $message);

    }
```

The problem is, when there's already a tagged link (with an "a" tag), regex is destroying the link.

Here is an example:

first input from textarea: Hello .... test.com

changed by regex: `Hello ... <a href="http://test.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="test.com">test.com</a>`

this is working fine, but if you update this:

```
Hello ... http://test.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="test.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="test.com">test.com">test.com">test.com
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In the question title you would like regular experssion to find <a></a> in your descrition your would like to match to URL-s. Which one do you need? :) Would you like search in a html code or in a raw text?

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML, use a DOM parser library like `DOMDocument`.

Comment: As you can see in the example, i'm looking for a way to only tag links without an <a> tag around... The big problem is, if i edit the post again, the regex adding another <a> tag to the previous <a> tag, so at the end the link is not working at all

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PHP and maybe this is not a good pattern for url validation, but the point is if there is already an "a" tag, the text is not replaced.

```
<?php

    $message = array(
        'Hello ... <a href="http://test.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="test.com">test.com</a>',
        "Hello .... http://www.test.com ..."
    );

    $url = '@(<a[^>]*>[^<]+</a>|((https?://)?[\w\.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}[^\s\W]*))@';

    foreach ($message as $msg) {

        preg_match($url, $msg, $matches);

        if(preg_match($url, $msg) == 1 && count($matches) > 2) {

            $msg = preg_replace($url, '<a href="$0" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="$0">$0</a>', $msg);

        }

        echo $msg.PHP_EOL;

    }

    // Output:
    // Hello ... <a href="http://test.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="test.com">test.com</a>
    // Hello .... <a href="http://www.test.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" title="http://www.test.com">http://www.test.com</a> ...
```

Hope it helps.